# Max flow min cut algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I am trying to work this max-flow, min-cut out for my finals, but Im really not sure I have got it, I would appreciate some assistance! I understand the theorm, I comes from ford-fulkerson, where the maximum capacity through a network is pushed in a number of steps. The minimal cut from s to t = max flow.

But this question is giving me a headache:

[image]

Assume x = 0 What is the maximal flow from s to t? I got 2

Assume x = 10 What is the maximal flow from s to t? I got 8

What is the maximal value of cut that separates s from t and does not cut any of the edges sa and bt? Explain why this value is the same as the value of the minimal cut when capacity x is very large.

Here I answer max cut that separates s from t = 2+x, because 2 is max cut when x=0.

Now here is where my brain starts to die...

Determine the minimal value of each of the following type of cuts.

1. The minimal value of a cut that does not cut any of the edges sa and bt. I got 2+x
2. The minimal value of cut that cut the edge sa but does not cut the edge bt. I got x+4
3. The minimal value of cut that cut the edge bt but does not cut the edge sa. I got 2+x
4. The minimal value of a cut that cut both the edge sa and bt. I got 4

Let f(x) denote the maximal flow from s to t expressed as a function of x. Sketch the graph of f(x) from 0  ≤ x ≤  10 (the results from the above question can be used  to help consider different cases) I dont even know where to start with this question :(

Has anyone got any suggestions to my attempt of these questions and a hint for the last question?

Answer (score 1):

> > Assume x = 0 What is the maximal flow from s to t? I got 2

This is correct.

> > Assume x = 10 What is the maximal flow from s to t? I got 8

This is incorrect. The first flow-augmenting path chosen is $s \to a \to t$ which augments the flow by $4$.

I then choose $s \to a \to b \to t$ (pushing flow back across the incoming arc with capacity $2$), which augments the flow by $2$.

I then choose $s \to b \to t$, which augments the flow by $5$.

Finally, I choose $s \to a \to b \to t$, pushing flow across the outgoing arc with capacity $1$.

So you push flow of $12$ through the graph.

> > The minimal value of a cut that does not cut any of the edges sa and bt. I got 2+x

How did you get this? The value of a cut is the capacity of the arcs going from one partition to the other. So if sa and bt must be together, we have: $[\{s, a\}, \{b, t\}]$. So we have arcs $(s, a), (a, b), (a, t)$. The sum of the capacities of those arcs is the value of your cut.

> > The minimal value of cut that cut the edge sa but does not cut the edge bt. I got x+4

So our cut is $[\{s\}, \{a, b, t\}]$. So then $x + 5$ is the value of the cut.

Can you take it from here with the other two cuts?

> > Let f(x) denote the maximal flow from s to t expressed as a function of x. Sketch the graph of f(x) from 0 ≤ x ≤ 10

Here is my hint. What happens when $x < 8$? What happens when $x > 8$? Consider how much flow you can push across the arc $(s, a)$ based on values of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

ml0105
you are wrong.

when x = 10
The max flow is 10.

augmenting paths:

s-a-t --->+4

s-b-t --->+5

s-a-b-t--->+1

notice that (a,t) ,(a,b), (s,b) are now saturated
and therefore max flow = 10. 
and the min cut is equal to {s,a}.

u can also check:

acording to visualgo 
(http://visualgo.net/maxflow.html), (u can draw any graph in visualgo)

when x = 10 the max flow = 10.